How to Create a table with spaces in column name
I am creating table in Snowflake.
The column name ‘Full Name’ must have a space in the middle. When I put it in double quotes it automatically put the underscore instead of space.
What is the syntax to create it with space in the middle?

Can you add your code?

If you have the liberty of deciding whether to use spaces in column names or not, it's considered a best practice to not use spaces in column names.

This works well - and if it doesn't for you, please share your code when asking a question:
create or replace table for_mike ("Your Name" varchar, age number);
insert into for_mike values ('Mike', 29);
select * from for_mike;


